# WPF RichTextBox ScrollToEnd gets stuck after many lines

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a Rich text box that gets updated very fast, and I am adding a lot of paragraphs per second. Each update I use ScrollToEnd in order to see the latest addition.
After a few seconds it gets stuck. If i remove the  ScrollToEnd it doesn't get stuck. But, I have to manually scroll down, which is not what I want.
What can be the problem ? how can I solve it.
Thanx.

Comment: Why not just do ScrollToEnd as the last step so it is only called once rather than on each insert?

Comment: please provide minimal viable code to reproduce this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or post your code to code review